# How to codesign and notarize an Os X app?

Tags: macos, code-signing, xojo, notarize

How to codesign and notarize an Os X app?

I'm using Xojo 2016r2.

Answer (score 4):

I was puzzled as how to do this, but then found the following link, which helped me a lot:

https://docs.xojo.com/UserGuide:Mac_Code_Signing

Here's what I did:

1. Downloaded and installed XCode on my system.
2. Signed up for Apple's Developer Program.
3. Created the required certificate(s).  (This is where the article comes in handy!)
4. I used an app called [DMGCanvas](https://www.araelium.com/dmgcanvas) to create the installer, which also code signed my program.